# Check if record exists

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access

I've the following database (*Note*: Dates are in dd-mm-yyyy format)

```
autoID  name     initialdate    finaldate

1    john        01-01-2016     05-01-2016
2    michael     01-02-2016     05-02-2016
3    andrew      01-01-2016     10-01-2016
......
```

The user will insert, via a simple HTML form, a new user, example

```
4    michael     01-03-2016     02-03-2016
```

Which returns OK, because the dates don't overlap.

However, I need that if they introduce one of this two examples, an error message shows and doesn't add the record:

```
4    michael     04-02-2016     10-02-2016     (note it starts on 04-02, which overlaps a record that already exists
```

or

```
4    michael     20-01-2016     02-02-2016     (same)
```

or

```
4    michael     02-02-2016     04-02-2016
```

or

```
4    michael     01-01-2016     20-02-2016
```

and so on.

How can I do it using ASP.net and an .mdb (access) database?

Comment: while you are inserting a new record check the min date for initialdate and max date for finaldate for the name and then see if the new record is in this range. Basically You will have to add a validation before adding the record.

Comment: Create function that will check if there is record for given name, use it to check if you have to run insert query or not.

Comment: @Gautam - yes, I Know, but I can't discover the logic for that validation... That's my problem.
Velid - sorry, not the case - the given name can be many times the same.

Comment: have you tried logic for the validation? if you have post the code so I can help you with it. If not where do you want to validate in sql or in c#?

Comment: @Gautam I don't have any code right now.

Comment: @Guatam Right now I'm trying to figure out the logic itself for the validation.. So it can be done on sql or vb.net...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figured out with many logical help from you.
That what I've come to:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
Conn.Open Server.MapPath("My_DB.mdb")
Set reg = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
checkit = "SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt FROM dados WHERE name = '" & TXTName & "' AND (dateinit <= " & TXTdateend & " AND " & TXTdateinit & " <= dateend)"
reg.Open checkit, Conn
 if check <> 0 then 
'code to use if dates overlap'
else
'code if dont' 
end if
```

I don't know if it is correct to do that way, but it does what I really need. Thanks!

Comment: "SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt FROM dados WHERE name = '" & TXTName & "' AND ((dateinit <= " & TXTdateend & " AND " & TXTdateinit & " <= dateend)  or (dateinit <= " & TXTdateinit & " AND " & TXTdateend& " <= dateend) or (dateinit >= " & TXTdateend & " AND " & TXTdateend  & " <= dateend) or (dateinit >= " & TXTdateinit & " AND " & TXTdateinit & " <= dateend) )"   you should all these conditions also as these condition also merge with the existing date range. Thats what I think. Take a look if this meets your requirement.

Comment: @Guatam thanks! But unfortunatelly, I didn't understand your logic.. Why should I have those aditional 2 verifications? "Merge with the existing date range"? Didn't understand..

Comment: (dateinit <= " & TXTdateend & " AND " & TXTdateinit & " <= dateend) For new date with in any previous interval. or(dateinit <= " & TXTdateinit & " AND " & TXTdateend& " <= dateend) for For previous interval falls with in new interval or (dateinit >= " & TXTdateend & " AND " & TXTdateend & " <= dateend) when new date interval starts before previous interval but falls in the interval or ends in previous interval or (dateinit >= " & TXTdateinit & " AND " & TXTdateinit & " <= dateend)  when new interval starts in previous interval and ends after the end of previous interval. Overlap in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

I'd run a query to check for pertinent records.  Let's assume your new record is entered into textboxes named txtName, txtInitialDate and txtFinalDate.  So, your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Name = '" & Me.txtName & "' 
  AND (InitialDate BETWEEN #" & Me.txtInitialDate & "# AND #" & Me.txtFinalDate & "#
  OR FinalDate BETWEEN #" & Me.txtInitialDate & "# AND #" & Me.txtFinalDate & "#)
```

This should give you all records where the name matches, and either of the dates entered is between InitialDate and FinalDate.  If your dates entered are between those two dates, you have an overlap.

Now, all you have to do is do a count of the number of rows in this query.  If RowCount > 0, it's a record that overlaps.  If RowCount = 0, there's no overlap.

Comment: Your suggestion has a couple of issues: 1) if you are just interested in the number of rows meeting the criteria, use ``SELECT COUNT(*)`` instead of retrieving all of those rows; 2) assembling SQL statements as strings using user input is prone to SQL injection attacks; use SQL parameters instead to mitigate that.

Comment: There's a risk of SQL injection in MSAccess??

Comment: If the values are being entered by the end-user, then yes, absolutely.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I used the "SELECT COUNT (*)". Right now, How can I put the count result on a variable (VB net)? So i can check "If variable <> 0 then...."

Comment: @JohnnyBones I managed to retrieve the count number. Now I have another "problem". The verification logic you provided, isn't 100% correct. I mean, let's supose I have a record for michael from 1-1-2016 to 10-1-2016. Let's suppose I want to insert a new one from 3-1-2016 to 8-1-2016. The right result would be the error - because the dates overlap. But instead, it is leting me insert this new value. Any ideas?